# When people talk about someone or something everywhere

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

I am looking for the most common way to say that people are talking about someone / something everywhere in English. There should be a common idiom which I can not find it. However I have translated several sentences of us. I would appreciate it that after having a look on them, let me know if they are natural and if not what shall I say instead to be quite natural in everyday speech:

> - He is the talk of the town.
> - He has become quite the hot topic for conversation around town.
> - He has become a household subject of conversation.

In our language we say:

> - Someone / something has fallen on top of the people's tongue. Meaning that people are talking about him / it and he / it has become the topic of discussions everywhere.

I am looking for an idiom to convey the same thing in English.

Comment: "talk of the town" is fine

Comment: You bet @TeacherKSHuang ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [be on everyone's lips](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+on+everyone's+lips)
>
> If a word or question is on everyone's lips, a lot of people are talking about it and interested in it.
>
> And the question that's on everyone's lips at the moment is, will he have to resign over the scandal?
>
> The Free Dictionary

This is the idiom that most closely resembles your original saying, I think, because it also involves a part of the mouth.

However, all three of the ones you had suggested were fine as well and I think everyone would understand your intended meaning.

Comment: A-friend. Let's put it this way. I would normally say, "His name is on everyone's lips," but I think everyone would understand you if you just say, "He is on everyone's lips."